Is "static int* foo()", in C, a static function returning a pointer, or a function returning a static pointer?
I'm working with an Arduino library I slightly modified for AVR C, which interfaces with an ICM-20948 IMU (Integrated Measurement Unit). In it, I found this "gem":
uint8_t* temp = read_multiple_icm20948_reg(ub_0, B0_TEMP_OUT_H, 2);

Where read_multiple... is defined as:
static uint8_t* read_multiple...(userbank ub, uint8_t reg, uint8_t len){
    static uint8_t reg_val[6];
    .
    .
    .
    return reg_val;
}

My question is, is this a static function that returns a pointer, or a regular function that returns a static pointer? And should I restructure it to look like this:
uint8_t* temp;
read_multiple_icm20948_reg(temp, ub_0, B0_TEMP_OUT_H, 2);

Where read_multiple... would be defined as
void read_multiple...(uint8_t *ret, userbank ub, uint8_t reg, uint8_t len);

To avoid undefined behaviour in the form of returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory.

It's a static function returning a pointer. What's a "static pointer" in this context anyway ?

Return types can never be static.

static is a storage-class specifier, which is not part of a type.

@wohlstad So, should I rewrite it to take a return pointer as an argument?

Since reg_val is itself static, it is not on the stack, and therefore AFAIK it is OK to return its address in the form of a pointer to it. Therefore your last sensence ("To avoid undefined behaviour in the form of returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory.") should not be a concern.

static has several totally different meanings. The two static in the code are examples of that - they don't do the same  thing.

@BoP Well they both alter the linkage of the object or function they apply to.

@IanAbbott - On the other hand, for the function the effect is visibilty and for the data the effect is its lifetime. Same, same, but different.

@n0rmi as requested I turned my comments into an answer, you can remove the last edit to your question.

@BoP True, the linkage (if any) and lifetime of an object both depend on the storage-class. True, the variable declared in the function body had no linkage anyway, so declaring it static had no effect on its linkage, only on its lifetime.

Turned my comments into an answer, as requested:

The function static int* foo() {  /* ... */ } (as well as read_multiple... or any similar function) is a static function returning a pointer.
There is no such thing as a "static pointer" in this context.
It's OK to return reg_val in the function read_multiple....
This is because reg_val is static, which means that it is not on the stack. Therefore it's OK to return its address in the form of a pointer to it.
Your last sentence:
"To avoid undefined behaviour in the form of returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory" should therefore not be a concern.


You cannot return storage class specifiers such as static from a function - storage class specifiers are only found at the line where an object/function is declared. The storage class specifier belongs with the specific object/function and not with the type of the object/function (unlike type qualifiers, const/volatile, which belong with the type).
The anonymous data which is returned from a function always has automatic storage duration and it is impossible to change that - you can change the type but not the storage duration.
So static in this case belongs with the function declaration/definition, meaning that the function has internal linkage and can only be called from within the translation unit where it is declared/defined. Otherwise functions use external linkage as default (even if you don't spell it out with extern) meaning they can be called from different translation units.
That the data pointed-at by the returned pointer happened to be static too is just a coincidence.
More info here: What does the static keyword do in C?


And should I restructure it

Static storage duration of private functions is the appropriate and correct way to design C code. And so you may actually have found a gem, but not in the sarcastic way you assumed - using static for private functions is simply how C programs are commonly and correctly written, even though you may not be aware of it.
Objects and functions should have as narrow scope as possible and external linkage should only be used for functions which are part of a library's "API" - the interface to the programmer using said library.
You are however correct assuming that a function returning a pointer is often a sign of a fishy design. But in this case the function is clearly meant to be some internal part of that library and not something exposed to the application programmer. In this context, returning a pointer to private static data means that the function is not interrupt- (or thread-/multiprocess-) safe, but the programmer probably did not intend for it to be either.
static uint8_t reg_val[6]; is however not allocated on the stack, since variables with static storage duration are typically allocated in either the .data or .bss segments of RAM. There is no undefined behavior here.
Specifically, the uint8_t* anonymous pointer object returned from the function has in itself automatic storage duration (stack or register allocation) but it points to an object with static storage duration (.data/.bss).
This might also be helpful: What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?
